# useEffect blocking render in React18

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to demonstrate the difference between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`, and I stumble upon something strange. Since React 18, effects seem to be blocking render when taking a long time, while in React 17 render was done (and screen painted) before the effect was triggered.

For example, if you have this in a component :

```js
function MyComponent() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    sleep(1000)
    console.log('effect done!')
  })

  return ...
}

// Sleep is a small util like this:
function sleep(time = 0) {
  const wakeUpTime = Date.now() + time;
  while (Date.now() < wakeUpTime) {}
}
```

In React 17, it would render the component and *only then* it would get "stuck" in this long useEffect. In React 18, it's actually blocking the render. Why ? Aren't effects supposed to be triggered asynchronously after render ?

I don't see the point of `useLayoutEffect` if the screen doesn't get painted before useEffect runs

I made two sandboxes to show the difference :

- With React 17 (working as expected) => https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-with-react-17-l8p0vd?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1249
- With React 18 (blocking render) => https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-with-react-18-o2qhtb?file=/src/App.tsx:87-192

Comment: In your sandbox I don't see the issue, it doesn't block the render. At least for me, I see it is rendered, then sleep then scroll, just like it should. I would argue that if you see something, most likely confusion caused by StrictMode, there were changes there from 17 to 18. Try without StrictMode

Comment: A potential answer would probably reference https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/128

Comment: @NikitaChayka Are you sure you're checking the React 18 sandbox? It would be really weird if you had a different behavior on your browser. I tried with and without strict mode, it doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I thought about that too, but I'm not sure that making a DOM update (here, scrolling a container) is a "discrete input".

Comment: @Alarid yes I am pretty sure :) refresh the page multiple times (I mean result page in codesandbox) and you will clearly see it. Also, try building it in prod. Again just because I see it renders and then effect after page refresh gives me an idea that it has something to do with development or ScrictMode

Comment: Also you can try increasing the sleep - you will see it renders first.

Comment: @NikitaChayka Well I'm confused: I **always** have a blank screen for the duration of the sleep on first render. Also, 100% of the time when I click on the button, I have to wait for the duration of the sleep to get the render. Maybe it doesn't behave like this once built, but I need to understand why it behaves like this in dev mode

Comment: Hm, about button you are right, but that actually is explainable by what is mentioned by @CertainPerformance. It is more clearly explained here - https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24195 (see **Consistent useEffect timing**). Simply - when button click is triggering re-render then useEffect is flushed synchronously. That's exactly your case

Comment: @NikitaChayka I see, so **it is** a discrete input in this case, because the re-render occurs after a user event. Makes sense, thanks

Comment: However, I tried replacing the user input (here, click on the button) with an interval that automatically add a message every 3 seconds, and it's still the same. Is an interval considered a discrete input ? That would be weird